# How to keep an IntentService running even when app is closed?

Tags: android, android-service, intentservice, android-intentservice

In my Android app I start an IntentService from within an Activity by calling

```
startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
```

And it works like a charm. I can move between Activies, press the Home button to switch to other apps... and it's still working. But if I remove my app from the recents screen, my service is stopped. How can I avoid this? In other words, how can I keep my service running even if my app is closed from recent apps?

My service code is as follows:

```
public class MyService extends IntentService {

public MyService() {
    super("MyService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    //Here I run a loop which takes some time to finish
}

}
```

Comment: IntentService is not running all the time but it works on Intent base. You send, lets say a command to do (do some job), using Intent and service executes that job and stops itself after that.

Comment: related for Service http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16651009/android-service-stops-when-app-is-closed

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562914/keeping-alive-intent-service-after-application-is-killed

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) is not running all the time but it works on Intent base. You send, lets say a command to do (do some job), using Intent and service executes that job and stops itself after that waiting for other Intent.
You should use usual [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) instead of IntentService to achive your goal. Service should be configured as `START_STICKY`.

Comment: No, I don't mean having my service running all the time. My service needs to do a long-running operation. What I need to do is that my service continues to do that operation even if my app is closed from recents. When it has finished, it should terminate itself

Comment: Again:You should use usual Service instead of IntentService to achive your goal.

Comment: I'm going to try it. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

in your service class `@Override`   [onStartCommand](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int%29) method

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
    // stopped, so return sticky.
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

To Kill a service itself, you can use [stopSelf()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#stopSelf%28%29)

Comment: Is this really safe? The docs stated `You should not override this method for your IntentService. Instead, override onHandleIntent(Intent), which the system calls when the IntentService receives a start request.`